# Mongodb: how to read value without knowing field name?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, field

I have a collection "A" that have documents:

```
{_id:1, a1: "degree"}
{_id:2, a2: "score"} ...
```

I need to transform that collection to key-value structure such as:

```
{_id: x, {name: "a1",  label: "degree"} }
{_id: y, {name: "a2",  label: "score"} }
```

Problem is every document can have different field name in collection A.
To get the field name, I can use javascript as follows,
But still can't find way to get each field value without knowing field name.

```
var arr = new Array()
var x = 0
var cur = db."A".find()
while( cur.hasNext() ) {
  var i = 0
  for( var field in cur[x] ) {
      arr[i] = field;    // get field name
      i++;}
db."B".save( { "name": arr[1], //fieldname
             "label":    //how to put value without knowing field name?
            )
  x++;
}
```

Do you have any idea how to get field value without knowing the name?
thank you.

Comment: You mean to `{_id: x, name: "a1",  label: "degree"}`

Comment: did you get the value of `_id` in the name field inside the loop?

Comment: No, _id doesn't matter what it has..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for comments and answers!
I have completed my javascript code as follows:

```
var arr = new Array()
var x = 0
var cur = db.A.find()
while( cur.hasNext() ) {
var i = 0
for( var field in cur[x] ) {
    arr[i] = field;    // get field name
    print( "field name="+ field);
    print( "the value="+cur[x][field] );
    i++;
    }
x++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure is this what you really want but hope this help.

Try this :

```
var obj = [
    {_id: x, {name: "a1",  label: "degree"} },
    {_id: y, {name: "a2",  label: "score"} }
];

for (index in obj) {
    for (key in obj[index]) {
        console.log(key); 
        console.log(obj[index][key]); 
    }
}
```